# Defer actions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, exception, monad-transformers

I'd like to defer actions. Therefore I use a `WriterT` that should remember actions that I `tell` him.

```
module Main where

import Control.Exception.Safe
       (Exception, MonadCatch, MonadThrow, SomeException,
        SomeException(SomeException), catch, throwM)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (MonadIO, liftIO)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Writer (WriterT, runWriterT, tell)

type Defer m a = WriterT (IO ()) m a

-- | Register an action that should be run later.
defer :: (Monad m) => IO () -> Defer m ()
defer = tell

-- | Ensures to run deferred actions even after an error has been thrown.
runDefer :: (MonadIO m, MonadCatch m) => Defer m () -> m ()
runDefer fn = do
  ((), deferredActions) <- runWriterT (catch fn onError)
  liftIO $ do
    putStrLn "run deferred actions"
    deferredActions

-- | Handle exceptions.
onError :: (MonadIO m) => MyException -> m ()
onError e = liftIO $ putStrLn $ "handle exception: " ++ show e

data MyException =
  MyException String

instance Exception MyException

instance Show MyException where
  show (MyException message) = "MyException(" ++ message ++ ")"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "start"
  runDefer $ do
    liftIO $ putStrLn "do stuff 1"
    defer $ putStrLn "cleanup 1"
    liftIO $ putStrLn "do stuff 2"
    defer $ putStrLn "cleanup 2"
    liftIO $ putStrLn "do stuff 3"
  putStrLn "end"
```

I get the expected output

```
start
do stuff 1
do stuff 2
do stuff 3
run deferred actions
cleanup 1
cleanup 2
end
```

However, if an exception is thrown

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "start"
  runDefer $ do
    liftIO $ putStrLn "do stuff 1"
    defer $ putStrLn "cleanup 1"
    liftIO $ putStrLn "do stuff 2"
    defer $ putStrLn "cleanup 2"
    liftIO $ putStrLn "do stuff 3"
    throwM $ MyException "exception after do stuff 3"
  putStrLn "end"
```

none of the deferred actions is run

```
start
do stuff 1
do stuff 2
do stuff 3
handle exception: MyException(exception after do stuff 3)
run deferred actions
end
```

but I expect this

```
start
do stuff 1
do stuff 2
do stuff 3
handle exception: MyException(exception after do stuff 3)
run deferred actions
cleanup 1
cleanup 2
end
```

The writer somehow looses his state. If I use `[IO ()]` as state instead of `IO ()`

```
type Defer m a = WriterT [IO ()] m a
```

and print the length of `deferredActions` in `runDefer` it is 2 on success  (because I called `defer` twice) and 0 on error (even though `defer` has been called twice).

What causes this issue? How can I run the deferred actions after an error?

Comment: The problem is the `MonadCatch` instance of `WriterT`. It defines `catch (WriterT m) h = WriterT $ m \`catch\` \e -> runWriterT (h e)`; note that when `m` throws an exception, the `WriterT` environment of `m` is discarded, and the one which is kept is that of `h e`. And of course `onError` does not `tell` any deferred actions. This is a limitation of `WriterT` itself, which is a value of type `m (a, w)` - if that `m` throws an error, you don't have access to the `w`, so you can't keep the environment after an error. Possibly you want the monad `\m w a -> (w, m a)` or `ExcepT e (WriterT w m)`.

Comment: @user2407038 That should probably be an answer.

Comment: @jkeuhlen I don't know, I think a complete answer would show what the example would look like with at least one of the two suggested alternative implementations proposed in the last sentence of my comment. As it stands, that last sentence is essentially a claim without proof (which I think is insufficient for an answer). Currently I'm unwilling to write such an answer, but maybe someone else will or I'll find time later.

Comment: @user2407038 Fair enough, I never said it would be a perfect answer, but at least 6 people found that comment helpful enough to upvote it.

Comment: @user2407038 Thank you very much. Your comment helped me to understand why my approach in the question doesn't work and pointed out another approach that helped me to find an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Like [user2407038](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2407038/user2407038) already [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45994157/defer-actions-in-haskell#comment78951644_45994157) it is not possible to get the state (deferred actions) in `catch`. However, you can use `ExceptT` to catch errors explicitly:

```
module Main where

import Control.Exception.Safe
       (Exception, Handler(Handler), MonadCatch,
        SomeException(SomeException), catch, catches, throw)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (MonadIO, liftIO)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (lift)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except (ExceptT, runExceptT, throwE)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Writer (WriterT, runWriterT, tell)

type DeferM m = WriterT (IO ()) m

type Defer m a = DeferM m a

-- | Register an action that should be run later.
--
defer :: (Monad m) => IO () -> Defer m ()
defer = tell

-- | Register an action that should be run later.
-- Use @deferE@ instead of @defer@ inside @ExceptT@.
deferE :: (Monad m) => IO () -> ExceptT e (DeferM m) ()
deferE = lift . defer

-- | Ensures to run deferred actions even after an error has been thrown.
--
runDefer :: (MonadIO m, MonadCatch m) => Defer m a -> m a
runDefer fn = do
  (result, deferredActions) <- runWriterT fn
  liftIO $ do
    putStrLn "run deferred actions"
    deferredActions
  return result

-- | Catch all errors that might be thrown in @f@.
--
catchIOError :: (MonadIO m) => IO a -> ExceptT SomeException m a
catchIOError f = do
  r <- liftIO (catch (Right <$> f) (return . Left))
  case r of
    (Left e) -> throwE e
    (Right c) -> return c

data MyException =
  MyException String

instance Exception MyException

instance Show MyException where
  show (MyException message) = "MyException(" ++ message ++ ")"

handleResult :: Show a => Either SomeException a -> IO ()
handleResult result =
  case result of
    Left e -> putStrLn $ "caught an exception " ++ show e
    Right _ -> putStrLn "no exception was thrown"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "start"
  runDefer $ do
    result <-runExceptT $ do
      catchIOError $ putStrLn "do stuff 1"
      deferE $ putStrLn "cleanup 1"
      catchIOError $ putStrLn "do stuff 2"
      deferE $ putStrLn "cleanup 2"
      catchIOError $ putStrLn "do stuff 3"
      catchIOError $ throw $ MyException "exception after do stuff 3"
      return "result"
    liftIO $ handleResult result
  putStrLn "end"
```

We get the expected output:

```
start
do stuff 1
do stuff 2
do stuff 3
handle my exception: "exception after do stuff 3"
run deferred actions
cleanup 1
cleanup 2
end
```

Notice that you have to catch errors explicitly using `catchIOError`. If you forget it and just call `liftIO`, the error will not be caught.

Note further that the call to `handleResult` is not safe. If it throws an error the deferred actions won't be run afterwards. You might consider to handle the result after the actions have been run:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "start"
  result <-
    runDefer $ do
      runExceptT $ do
        catchIOError $ putStrLn "do stuff 1"
        deferE $ putStrLn "cleanup 1"
        catchIOError $ putStrLn "do stuff 2"
        deferE $ putStrLn "cleanup 2"
        catchIOError $ putStrLn "do stuff 3"
        catchIOError $ throw $ MyException "exception after do stuff 3"
        return "result"
  handleResult result
  putStrLn "end"
```

Otherwise, you have to catch that error separately.

---

**Edit 1:** Introduce `safeIO`

**Edit 2:**

- use simpler error handling
- use `safeIO` in all snippets
- warn of exceptions in `handleResult`

**Edit 3:** Replace `safeIO` with `catchIOError`.

Comment: Note that `safeIO` doesn't need to be lifted in this code (i.e., the definition `safeIO = catchIOError` works just as well) because `catchIOError` is already taking an `IO a` and lifting it.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr Thanks, how could I oversee that. I've updated my answer.